# Compiler error: Unexpected symbol '}'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

I have an error in my C# code that I cannot find. I edited it in Notepad++ for Unity 5.2.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SplashScreenDelayed : MonoBehaviour {
    public float delayTime = 3;

    IEnumerator Start(){        
    yield return new WaitForSeconds( delayTime );

    Aplication.LoadLevel( 1 )
    }
}
```

I am getting the following errors when trying to compile:

[image: https://gyazo.com/1eaac4cb7f683235896b9f282c85863d]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I needed to fix "Aplication" to Application and to add ";"
at the end of a line.

Now the code looks like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SplashScreenDelayed : MonoBehaviour {
    public float delayTime = 3;

    IEnumerator Start(){        
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayTime);

    Application.LoadLevel(1);
    }
}
```

But unity says that Application.LoadLevel is obselete.

Comment: there is also missing an f at the end of the float ---> 3f

Comment: You may need to import `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` and then use `SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName)`. This is the new way of doing it, and `Application.LoadLevel` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

In 5.3, loading a scene a bit different. Use the namespace `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;`

`Application.LoadLevel("SceneName");` equals `SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneName");`

Visit [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) page for definitions.